# I can't find Vigilant Tyranus and can't start 'The House of Horrors' quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't find Vigilant Tyranus and can't start 'The House of Horrors' quest. I went to the Silver Blood Inn and tried rumours but there wasn't even a dialogue for it. I wanted to do the quest and now I don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "skipped"? What platform are you on, there's a bunch of PS3/4 bugs on the wiki with workarounds.

Comment: And what mission to help Tyranus? Encountering him starts House of Horrors. Where does the Silver Blood Inn enter into this?

Comment: There's nothing to skip. He is supposed to just stand there indefinitely until you agree to help him. UESP [says](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vigilant_Tyranus) he sometimes wanders off to the city's stables, but other than that, there's no such thing as "skipping" that quest. There's only "do it now" vs. "do it later."

Comment: Voting to leave open. The core of the issue here is that OP can't find Vigilant Tyranus, and can't start the related quest, 'The House of Horrors' (hence, the quest hasn't been "skipped").